# Does time pass for King Midas' victims?

Tags: percy-jackson, rick-riordan, the-heroes-of-olympus

When [Piper Mclean](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Piper_McLean) was turned to gold in *[The Lost Hero](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Hero)*, it is said that she had a dream. This would imply that it is like being asleep, therefore time passes.

However, [King Midas](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Midas) had victims from thousands of years ago (e.g. his [daughter](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Zoe), his barber, etc), who also came back to life.

Does time not pass for King Midas' victims, or does time pass really slowly, like [Thalia](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Thalia_Grace) when she was a great [pine tree](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Thalia's_Pine_Tree) (Except a lot slower)?

Comment: I need to double check but isn't Piper pretty much the **only** data point for this in canon?

Comment: @DVK: Leo would too, I guess, but we don't have his point of view on it.

Answer (score 3):

Thalia does make a pretty good metaphor for this.
It makes sense that Thalia would age, because the tree is living, and it grows and ages, so she aged at a tree's pace. But gold doesn't age, so, in theory, time could pass without Midas's victims aging either.
I'm not sure about dreaming. I think Thalia visited Percy's dream in lightning thief, while she was still a tree, but tree dreaming rules might be different. I don't remember what Piper was dreaming about, but it might be important to answering this.

Comment: Piper dreamed about an old man with donkey ears chasing her and shouting "Your it!"

Comment: You know, maybe that was just shock @Mithical. That dream could even have been after the whole experience